# Graph Theory - chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

Draw a planar graph that is 4-chromatic that has both a Hamilton circuit and a Euler cycle. Assign appropriate colors to each vertex and denote a Hamilton circuit and Euler cycle that are present.

I currently have a graph that is a square with 4 edges. Would this work?

Comment: A square can be colored with $2$ colors. You can try with putting another roof at the bottom of the [House X Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HouseGraph.html).

Comment: That would satisfy the 4-chromatic case, but would it satisfy the other two conditions? specifically Hamilton Circuit?

Comment: For Hamilton cycle you can travel all vertices following the loop of the edges in the outside. Let me see if I find a picture of it.

Comment: [This one](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses-images/wp-content/uploads/sites/1141/2017/03/16191250/Try-It-Now-3-Graph-Theory.png), but in which $D$ is not a vertex. Instead, there is as edge from $B$ directly to $F$ and an edge from $C$ directly to $E$.

Comment: Hamiltonian cycle could be $ACFGEBA$. Eulerian cycle can be $BACEFBCFGEB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete graph on $4$ vertices is $4$-chromatic and has a Hamiltonian cycle.

To complete the example, ensure it has an Eulerian cycle by simply drawing an extra edge between each of two pairs of vertices.

Comment: That would require using a graph with multiple edges, which generally is not allowed.

Comment: The question only specifies a planar graph. But the OP can say whether a simple graph is required.